# Custom UITableViewCell Constraints not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, constraints, ios8.3

I have a nib that I load for a custom UITableViewCell that I added the missing constraints to in the bottom far right menu item that looks like this:

[image]

When I don't use auto constrains, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I click "Add Missing Constraints", it ends up like this:

[image]

I would like it so that the "Pts" label is a certain number of pixels from the right edge(so it aligns with the blue dashed margin line), but it never seems to work. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the label you want to constrain, click in the icon indicate in the pic bellow, select the right constrain line in the top the view where says add constrains, you add by clicking in the red line, enter the distance in point from the right margin you want (if you select constrain to margin it will use the blue lines you are taking about, if you uncheck it till count from the board of the frame. Select a top or button constrain as well, in the last dropbox select update frames and click add constraints. Done!

[image]

Here is an exemple of what the constrains look like

[image]

Also don't forget that now you can debug views in xCode using the button in the pic bellow

[image]

Comment: Can you post a printscreen of your constrains? Like the pic I upload in the answer

Comment: Thanks, that helped make it like I wanted. Apparently, the real problem was the table view had no constraints, so the actual size of it was extending over the screen

Comment: @BobRon I add a new comment in the answer that will help you figure out things like that in the future, it happens a lot I must say. Good luck with the rest of your project.